# Countour Mapping API

Tags: data, map, heatmap

I have done some searching on Google, but haven't come up with much as of yet. I am wanting to take a set of point data, which I had previously been using to create weighted points for a heat map through the Google API, and turn them into a contour map to overlay on the Google Maps API. I haven't seen anything in Google's code that would let me do this. Does anyone know of a good API to create such an overlay? Or is there possibly something I have overlooked that Google offers?

Comment: Did you check on [GIS SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I hadn't- I wasn't aware it existed.  I'll give it a shot though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I got this straight: You have something like [this](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles.html) or [this](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/toomanymarkers/toomanymarkers.html)? And you want something like [this](http://home.provide.net/~bratliff/polycluster/v3/absurd.html) or [this](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/layers/layers.html) or [this](http://www.usnaviguide.com/v3maps/ProjectedOverlayTest.htm)? Feel free to browse through the [sample gallery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery) and let me know if anything from there (partially) matches your requirements. Anything should be doable with Google Maps, if you're willing to spend enough time understanding how to leverage the full power of their Javascript API (and some of its undocumented features).

Comment: That's not QUITE what I'm looking for- I'm looking for something more like [this](https://www.midwestiso.org/marketsoperations/realtimemarketdata/pages/lmpcontourmap.aspx).  I am trying to avoid the way the image changes with the zoom level in a heatmap- I want it to be slightly more static than that, and having set ranges like this map would be useful as the data is a bit too granular at high zoom levels- having solid bands of color would make the map more useful in this context.

Comment: So, basically you want to disable zooming? Here ya' go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330197/how-to-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-scaling-with-google-maps-api :) Regarding the solid bands of color, I'm 100% sure that it can be done, but you'll have to do some research yourself into the matter. Maybe the experimental Fusion Tables https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables feature can help you achieve your goal. This example looks promising: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-styling

Comment: Also, look at the Fusion Table Heatmaps example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-heatmap If you decide to use this feature, make sure that you read its limitations first https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables

Comment: disabling zoom won't solve my problem, as I have been unable to find any way to predict what the data's radius of influence is- basically, I have to do trial-and-error for each individual map, and there are thousands of possible maps.  I have done some research on the issue, but I haven't found much in the way of APIs that will help make the contours- only massive algorithms for creating them (you wouldn't want to use them dynamically).  I haven't looked much at the Fusion Table stuff yet though- I took a quick look, but I'll go over it more closely.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Well, yeah, in that case it can get a bit hairy, but, on the other hand, I think you can get Google to do the hard part for you. You should be able to extract kml data somehow and then reuse it in Fusion Tables. Unfortunately, I can't help you any more than this, because I'm not familiar enough with such functionality. Good luck finding a solution.

Comment: Well, I looked into the Fusion Tables a bit, and it didn't seem very promising- as far as I could tell, the only thing that would help with is getting KML data.  I looked into GRASS for the v.surf.rst functionality, but as far as I could tell that was mostly a standalone solution.  Anyone else have any suggestions?